# Excel not recognising differences between various times

Tags: excel, vba, formula

This problem is a little odd but I'll try to describe it the best that I can.
I have a worksheet that functions as a timesheet. Column J has a specific shift time, say 06:00-16:30 (a 10.5 hour shift).
I then use text to columns to split out the start and end times of the shift into columns K & L.
Then in column M i have the formula =(MOD(L23-K23,1))*24 to work out the total number of shift hours. You'll then see below that i have a few lines of code to deduct 0.5 hours for breaks on any shifts >= 10.5 hours. This works fine for most shift times but 07:00-17:30 and 10:00-20:30 dont flag us as being 10.5 hours. Even though if I try to confirm what excel thinks the number is, by using =IF(M23 =10.5,TRUE) it returns TRUE so excel does think that figure is 10.5 but the macro doesn't. Complex i know but this is a weird problem

```
        'PLACE SHIFT TIMES
       Range("J23:J117").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("K23"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="-", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
 
Dim H As Integer

Dim PAIDHOURS As Range
Set PAIDHOURS = Range("N23:N117")
Dim WKD As String
 WKD = WKD

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True

'WKD AND MORE THAN 10.5
For H = 23 To 117
If Sheet5.Cells(H, 5).Value = "WKD" And Sheet5.Cells(H, 13).Value >= 10.5 Then
Sheet5.Cells(H, 14).Value = Sheet5.Cells(H, 13).Value - 0.5
End If
Next H
```

Comment: Just a guess, but might it be an accuracy error? Try rounding the value to 1 or 2 decimal places to see if it resolves the issue. Or make it `>= 10.49` ?

Comment: looks like the >=10.49 has worked. thanks for the help